# Vectors ( Resolution of vectors )

Tags: reference-frames, vectors, linear-algebra

How many components can a vector be resolved into?

I think that it should be infinity because there can be infinite axes. Am I right?

Comment: A vector belongs to a vector space, and the number of *linearly independent* components will equal the dimension of the space. Does that answer your question?

Comment: No, this usage assumes orthogonal components. The answer is 3 for a 3-D vector and 2 for a vector confined to a plane.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, a vector can be decomposed into a sum of an infinite number of vectors. These vectors are, however, not linearly independent. In a vector space of dimension n, you can decompose a vector, in general, into n linearly independent vectors. N linearly independent vectors of a vector space of dimension N are called a base of the vector space because any vector of the vector space can be obtained by a linear combination of the base vectors.

Answer (score 0):

A loose defining of vector resolution is with what vectors could you replace a given vector to produce the same result. In that sense you are correct.

But this is of little use in Physics. I suspect you're working in 2D. In that case, vector resolution always results in just two components when applied to the solution of a real world (or homework) problem. The reason is due to why we resolve vectors. Let's take projectile motion as an example. Shoot a cannonball, or any other object, upward at an angle between horizontal and vertical. That object, after launch and ignoring air resistance, will only be acted upon by gravity. So we resolve its motion into a vertical component that is completely affected by gravity, experiencing uniform acceleration, and a horizontal component, unaffected by gravity, whose velocity remains constant. This makes the problem much easier than considering a force (gravity in this example) acting at an angle.

There are many other examples of why two components, in 2D physics, are the only useful ones in problem solving. So while you are theoretical correct, for practical use 2D vectors are resolved into two perpendicular components.